# JMeter - groovy MultipleCompilationErrorsException in JSR223 Sampler

Tags: jmeter

I'm using groovy for `JMeter JSR223 sampler` . Below code is working fine from `JMeter GUI`.

```
String user = vars.get("username"); # abc.com\user1
String domainVal = ""
String userVal = ""
System.out.println(user)
if(user.contains("\\")){
    String[] arrOfStr = user.split("\\\\", 2); 
    domainVal =arrOfStr[0]
    userVal = arrOfStr[1]
}else{
    userVal = user
}
System.out.println(domainVal)
System.out.println(userVal)
```

But same script I'm trying from `JMeter headless` is giving me error

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script8.groovy: 20: Missing ')' @ line 20, column 18.
   if(user.contains("\")){
                    ^

1 error
```

I am clueless , what is causing the issue .

**Update**
I found the root cause it is caused by , if I remove below line (Jmeter thread number) it's working fine. Not a groovy issue, `JMeter` issue for sure.

> ```
> int thread_count = ${__threadNum};
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use JMeter function in JSR223 script, replacement for [__threadNum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter):

```
int threadNum = ctx.getThreadNum()
```

> The function returns a number between one and the max number of running threads. Note that if you're using JSR223 code with JMeterContext object (ctx variable), the below code returns a number between zero and (max number of running threads minus one)
> `ctx.getThreadNum()`

Comment: Yes I am able to fix it by int thread_count = ctx.getThreadNum() . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue:

[image]

with regards to your `int thread_count = ${__threadNum};` piece of "code", you shouldn't be inlining JMeter Functions or Variables into Groovy scripts because:

- The syntax conflicts with Groovy's [GString Template Engine](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html#_gstringtemplateengine)
- The values will be cached and re-used on next occurrence

So you should either use "Parameters" section or code-based equivalents

More information: [JSR223 Sampler Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

[image]

where `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class, see Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy article for more details on this and other JMeter API shorthands available for JSR223 Test Elements

Comment: Yes I am able to fix it by `int thread_count = ctx.getThreadNum()` . Thanks

Comment: If you add this `int thread_count = ${__threadNum};` to the groovy script , you will see the issue

Comment: If you add `this shit will not work` to the groovy script you will see the issue as well